# node privacy byrole in drupal

Tags: drupal

hi i have installed node privacy byrole module from http://drupal.org/project/node_privacy_byrole.when i enable this module some content displaying form from home page.but when i loged in every thing displaying as it was showing previous.
how can i resole this issue. although i have given the view permission for annoymus user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm understanding you right your asking why when you log in you can see everything this is probably because you are logged in as the superuser or user 1 if you are not logging inas the first user you created try checking permissions for the user group of your logged in user